# Inverse estimate of gradient of Sobolev function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, estimation

I need an estimate for $\| \nabla w\|_{L^2{(\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n)}}$, such that it is $< c\| w\|,\  w \in H_0^1(\Omega)\ $. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by $\|w\|$? Is it the $H^1_0$ norm or the $L^2$ norm of $w$?

Comment: It is the $L^2$-norm.

Answer (score 2):

Let us take $\phi\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus\{0\}$ with $\operatorname*{supp}\phi \subset B(0;1)$. For each $1>\epsilon>0$, let us define $\phi_\epsilon\in C^{\infty}_{0}(B(0;1))\setminus\{0\}$, by
$$
\phi_\epsilon (x):=\frac{1}{\epsilon^{\frac{n}{2}}}\varphi\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right),\text{ for all }x\in B(0;1).
$$
Clearly $\operatorname*{supp}\phi_\epsilon \subset B(0;\epsilon)$. for all $\epsilon>0$.
Note that,
$\Vert\phi_\epsilon\Vert_{L^2}=\Vert\phi\Vert_{L^2}$, for all $\epsilon>0$,
and 
$$\Vert \nabla\phi_\epsilon\Vert_{L^2}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Vert \nabla \phi\Vert_{L^2},\text{ for all }\epsilon>0,
$$
which shows that there can be no estimate of the form 
$$
\Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2}\leqslant C\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}, \text{ for all }u\in H^1_{0}(B(0;1)).
$$